# Docker Image for Dotnet Core 2.2 seems to not exist in new repo

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, .net-core

In visual Studio 2017, if you do a 'Add>Add Docker support' to a project, you get the old Repo:
microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime  location.

I figured, that must be now:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2 AS base

And:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build

Doing that, allows it to build OK, however, when I run it to my utter amazement, I get:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /usr/share/dotnet/
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

In the error log for the image when I try to run it..

Which implies that I shouldn't be using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2   Because it doesn't include the DotNet Core 2.2 runtime!   If not, they sure named it poorly!

Also, I just updated Visual Studio 2017, and it still generates a bogus Docker file that won't work, clearly, that needs fixed.

What is the correct Image for Dotnet Core 2.2?

It shouldn't matter, but I'm running this under Kubernetes / Docker Desktop

(Also, if I change the runtime to use the full version that I did the build on, it works!  I just tried this after I wrote this...)

Comment: .NET core 2.2 reached end of life in december 2019 and the images have been removed. I'm surprised VS2017 creates a Dockerfile that uses it. Is your VS up to date? The current LTS version is 6.0.

Comment: It has reached EOL, but the image still exist.  As stated above, I just updated my VS2017 yesterday, so it is up to date, but unfortunately, is un-aware of the move of the images to mcr Repo...

Comment: Sorry, I thought they'd been removed. Anyway, your issue is that the `runtime` images only contain the bare .NET runtime. You seem to be using ASP.NET, so you need to use the `aspnet` image which contains the .NET runtime + ASP.NET.